# How to add additional field in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join, nopcommerce

I want to add additional field in Domain(Nop.Core => Domain) which dont want to include in table field in nopcommerce 4.3. Actually, I want this because I want to fetch data from different tables in service query.

Here is my code :

```
protected virtual IQueryable<CustomerWastage> GetCustomerWastageQuery(int customerId)
{
    var query = (from customerWastage in _customerWastageRepository.Table
                 join product in _productMasterRepository.Table on customerWastage.ProductID equals product.Id
                 join carat in _caratMasterRepository.Table on customerWastage.CaratID equals carat.Id
                 where customerWastage.CustomerID ==   customerId                
                select new CustomerWastage() { Wastage = customerWastage.Wastage, ProductName = product.Name,  
                Carat = carat.Carat, CustomerID = customerWastage.CustomerID });

    return query;
}
```

Here **CustomerWastage** is a domain name and in that i want to add additional field i.e.

```
public string productname {get; set;} 
public string Carat {get; set;}
```

But dont want to mapped in table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this answers your question, but you could use the `[NotMapped]` attribute to specify that a class or property is not to be mapped to the database.

Example:

```
public string productname {get; set;} 
public string Carat {get; set;}

[NotMapped]
public string PropertyName { get; set; }
```